# Why div element will separate when re sizing even though I have inline-block?

Tags: html, css

When I shrink the browser + button separated between checkbox event though both div have inline-block

[image]

Please see the mini version of the code:

```
<div style="display: inline-block;">
  <a class="plus" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#data" href="#">
    <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i><span></span>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="checkbox name" style="font-size: 17px; display: inline-block; margin-left: 5px;">
  <label>
    <input name="unique_id" value="" type="checkbox">
    <div id="unique_id">name - address <span class="label label-info">display</span>
    </div>
  </label>
</div>
```

But I just want + button and check box will place together when re sizing like this image( without re size )

[image]

Comment: When asking about CSS, please create a https://jsfiddle.net or some way to test the code.

Comment: Please add your CSS to this question so that we can help.

Comment: Is there any particular reason to store those elements in different DIVs?

Answer (score 1):

When using `inline-block` on your elements they wrap with the parent width. So if you have a parent DIV to your structure juste add `white-space: nowrap;` to it. It will prevent the children with ìnline-block`to wrap (go under).

EDIT : You could also simplify your HTML structure, you have a lot of elements for a simple thing.

Comment: Thanks for the nice explanation... I checked .. it's working

Comment: @Rosini If you think this answer the question and is the best answer please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Set the width to both Div or add "float:left" to both div with some width to second div.

Comment: this is just partial solution and will wot work for example when wrapper div not be enough wide.

Answer (score 0):

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

will force the content to stay on one line

Answer (score 0):

Does it fit nicely if you made one of the divs a little shorter?

Reason because even with inline-block, two divs with a width of 50% might not actually fit in one row. There's a little space in between them. Not sure where it comes from; someone here should be able to provide the exact reason why.

But for me personally, what I'll do is wrap the two divs and give that parent div `style="font-size:0;"`. Only caveat with this is that you must explicitly set the font sizes of the children div.

[See JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/irot/49ag61op/)